# Can't configure cordova email plugin

Tags: plugins, cordova

I'm using Cordova 3.1 building an Android app. I'm trying to configure the email composer plugin using

cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git

When I add the android platform via the CLI it says the email-composer is installed, I can see it in android.json, and I even added a feature tag for it in config.xml as follows:

```
<feature name="EmailComposer">
    <param name="android-package" value="de.applant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" />
</feature>
```

the cordova_plugins.js file in platforms\android\assets\www contains and entry for the plugin with "clobbers":["plugin.email"]

When I try to reference one of the object methods using the following code:

```
window.plugin.email.isServiceAvailable
```

I get the following error:

object "call to unknown plugin: EmailComposer".

Is there another step I'm missing to configure the plugin?

Comment: are you using cordova build android after you install the plugin? Looks like you're missing the java file in src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/emailcomposer or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I'm using cordova build android. EmailComposer.java does exist in platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\emailcomposer. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: I set up a new project and the plugin loads just fine. If I resolve whatever is conflicting in my main project I'll post here for reference.

Comment: have you tested uninstall/reinstall the plugin in the old project?

Comment: Tried uninstall/reinstall. No luck but thanks.

Comment: Updated my primary project to Cordova 3.4, jQuery 2.1, and jqm 1.4 and the email plugin now works. Too many variables to worry about tracking down what actually fixed it so I'll leave it at that for now.